# Accessing attributes of session throws NullPointerException error, when using WicketTester

Tags: java, wicket

Accessing attributes of session throws NullPointerException error, when using WicketTester.

There was similar question asked earlier
[wicket 9: unit testing + mockito + httpSession](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70258881/wicket-9-unit-testing-mockito-httpsession)

The discussion their suggested using

tester.getRequest().getSession().setAttribute("userName", "Test user 1");

instead of

tester.getHttpSession().setAttribute("userName", "Test user 1");

Making that change did not resolve the problem.
Complete project, created using 'wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html' can be found at github.com/rjngshn/WicketTesterSession

```
    public class TestHomePage
{
    private WicketTester tester;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp()
    {
        tester = new WicketTester(new RTApplication());
    }
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70258881/wicket-9-unit-testing-mockito-httpsession
    @Test
    public void userPageRendersSuccessfully()
    {
        System.out.println("Testing userPageRendersSuccessfully ");
        tester.getRequest().getSession().setAttribute("userName", "Test user 1");
        System.out.println("Uesr name in session:" + tester.getHttpSession().getAttribute("userName"));
        //start and render the test page
        tester.startPage(UserPage.class);
        //assert rendered page class
        tester.assertRenderedPage(UserPage.class);
        tester.assertModelValue("txtUserName", "Test user 1");
        System.out.println("Complete testing userPageRendersSuccessfully ");
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
 [WARN] [stderr] java.lang.NullPointerException
 [WARN] [stderr]    at uk.ac.ox.ndph.ckb.UserPage.onInitialize(UserPage.java:19)
 [WARN] [stderr]    at org.apache.wicket.Component.fireInitialize(Component.java:883)
 [WARN] [stderr]    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.internalInitialize(MarkupContainer.java:1045)
```

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
diff --git ResearchTracker/src/test/java/uk/ac/ox/ndph/ckb/TestHomePage.java ResearchTracker/src/test/java/uk/ac/ox/ndph/ckb/TestHomePage.java
index 757269f..a9df941 100644
--- ResearchTracker/src/test/java/uk/ac/ox/ndph/ckb/TestHomePage.java
+++ ResearchTracker/src/test/java/uk/ac/ox/ndph/ckb/TestHomePage.java
@@ -21,8 +21,8 @@ public class TestHomePage
     public void userPageRendersSuccessfully()
     {
         System.out.println("Testing userPageRendersSuccessfully ");
-        tester.getRequest().getSession().setAttribute("userName", "Test user 1");
-        System.out.println("Uesr name in session:" + tester.getHttpSession().getAttribute("userName"));
+        tester.getSession().setAttribute("userName", "Test user 1");
+        System.out.println("Uesr name in session:" + tester.getSession().getAttribute("userName"));
         //start and render the test page
         tester.startPage(UserPage.class);
         //assert rendered page class
```

It seems you confuse the Wicket Session (`org.apache.wicket.Session`) with the HttpSession.
In the test you set the attribute on the HttpSession, while in `UserPage` you tried to read it from the Wicket Session.

Comment: Thank you very much.

I have now modified the project and it works correctly.

Working project code can be found at 'github.com/rjngshn/WicketTesterSession'